# ruby regex: how to get group value

Tags: ruby, regex

Here is my regex:

```
s = /(?<head>http|https):\/\/(?<host>[^\/]+)/.match("http://www.myhost.com")
```

How do I get the `head` and `host` groups?

Comment: Why don't you reuse an invented wheel, like Ruby's built-in [URI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html) or [Addressable::URI](http://addressable.rubyforge.org)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
s['head'] => "http"
s['host'] => "www.myhost.com"
```

You could also use URI...

```
1.9.3p327 > require 'uri'
 => true 
1.9.3p327 > u = URI.parse("http://www.myhost.com")
 => #<URI::HTTP:0x007f8bca2239b0 URL:http://www.myhost.com> 
1.9.3p327 > u.scheme
 => "http" 
1.9.3p327 > u.host
 => "www.myhost.com"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `captures` >>

```
string = ...
one, two, three = string.match(/pattern/).captures
```

Comment: How do you do this in context, ie, with his regex?

Comment: @JustJake - With your "current" regex pattern (with some minor optimization) it would be `head, host = "http://www.myhost.com".match(/(https?):\/\/([^\/]+)/).captures`. As you can see, the regex pattern has two groups `(...)`, and their matches will be assigned into `head, host`.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use the uri library for this purpose as suggested above, but whenever you match a string to a regex, you can grab captured values using the special variable:

> "foo bar baz" =~ /(bar)\s(baz)/
>
> $1

=> 'bar'

> $2

=> 'baz'

and so on...